# Split string and use as a class name

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I want to split a comma separated string, into a string with no commas, and then use the output as a class name.

Ex. I have a string like so: "Meat,Dog", and then I convert everything to lowercase, and then split the string, so it would look like: "meat dog"
How do i do this?

What I got so far is:

```
var tags = item.GetPropertyValue<string>("blogCats").ToLower().Split(' ');

<article class="@tags">

</article>
```

However, this just returns "System.String[];"

Comment: Do you really want to split it or just replace the comma with a space? Just do `item.GetPropertyValue<string>("blogCats").ToLower().Replace(',', ' ');`. I have a hunch that your problem is actually `item.GetPropertyValue<string>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace comma with space, no need to split

```
str.Replace(',', ' ')
```

In your case

```
item.GetPropertyValue<string>("blogCats").ToLower().Replace(',', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The split method returns an array of elements divided using the character you provided as parameter.

If you want to show it in a razor view, you just need to iterate over it using foreach statement.

As already suggested, you can instead use

```
str.Replace(',', ' ')
```

If all you want is a simple line of text.
Personally, I would recommend the using the array, though, as it seems it's tags you want to show on site somehow, and it seems likely that you'll want to do more than just print them as a string at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Variable "tags" returned by your code is array of string, you should use string.join:

```
<article class="@string.Join(" ",tags)">

</article>
```